# How to capture patterns with symbol prefix?

Tags: python, regex

I'm playing around with regex in Python and I'm facing some issues capturing some patterns.

I need to capture every tokens with an '%' prefix, it can appears in different ways but I need to collect only the following ones:

```
case 1: %Y
case 2: -p %U %y %y %p asd%a%a 
case 3: -p 8080 %M %a %x %y some_variable another_one %_capture_this %and_this %this%no neither%this %e
```

So if I use `re.findall` I should get:

```
output 1: ['%Y']
output 2: ['%U','%y','%y','%p']
output 3: ['%M','%a','%x','%y','%_capture_this','%and_this','%e']
```

I tried with:

```
regex = r'(\%\w+)|(?:\%\w+\%\w+)|(?:\w+\%\w+)'
```

But it's capturing `asd%a%a` and `%this%not` in both groups ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGIqFU/1)).

I need to exclude both, how can I fix this regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\B\%\w+\b(?!%)', text)`. I think your expected output is wrong in the question.

Comment: Why is there only `%U` in case 2 and not `%y`, `%y`, `%p`

Comment: Sorry my bad .. corrected

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew that's it

Comment: @maudev Then please consider accepting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58881965/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\B%\w+\b(?!%)', text)
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/546ET8/1)

**Regex details**

- `\B` - a non-word boundary that requires that the next `%` can't have a word char before it
- `%` - a `%` char
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (letters/digits/underscores)
- `\b` - a word boundary, the last char matched with `\w+` cannot be followed with a word char (it must be used because there is a negative lookahead after `\w+` to avoid backtracking)
- `(?!%)` - immediately to the right, there must be no `%` char.

Answer (score 1):

Try below regex, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZyYmUi/4) is here.

```
import re
s = "case 3: -p 8080 %M %a %x %y some_variable another_one %_capture_this %and_this %this%no neither%this %e"
re.findall(r'(?<=\s)\%\w+(?=\s|$)', s)
```

Output

```
['%M', '%a', '%x', '%y', '%_capture_this', '%and_this', '%e']
```

Comment: Actually your output is: `['%M', '%a', '%x', '%y', '%_capture_this', '%and_this', '%this', '%e']`. Means, you also match `%this`, although it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it. Corrected

Comment: Hi thanks for help, this works fine with all cases but there is a little: if the input is `str1 = "%Y"` it doesn't capturing it, erase the text `case 1` and check it, there can be some cases with no spaces at sides

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\B%\w+(?=\s|$)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qgx3ic/1)**

[image]